# OpenLayers is blurring the ImageLayer (Raster Image)

Tags: raster, openlayers, image, mapcanvas

I'm trying to use an 8192 x 4096px Image as a layer in OpenLayers and my code is as followed

```js
import Map from "ol/Map";
import View from "ol/View";
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/Tile";
import ImageLayer from "ol/layer/Image";
import Static from "ol/source/ImageStatic";
import Projection from "ol/proj/Projection";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function OpenLayers() {
  useEffect( async() => {
    var map = new Map({
      target: "map",
      view: new View({
        projection: "EPSG:4326",
        extent: [-180, -90, 180, 90],
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 0,
      }),
    });
    const image_2016 = new ImageLayer({
      source: new Static({
        url: "/assets/img/BlackMarble_2016.webp",
        projection: new Projection({
          code: "BlackMarble_2016",
          units: "pixels",
          extent: [-180, -90, 180, 90],
        }),
        imageExtent: [-180, -90, 180, 90],
      }),
    });
    map.addLayer(image_2016);
}, []);
  return (
    <>
      <div id="container" style={{ height: '0', overflow: "hidden" }}>
        <div id="map" style={{ height: "4096px", width: "8192px" }}></div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The issue here is the image rendered by OpenLayers is 20-30% blurred from original ones and isn't sharp and crisp.

Original Image Screenshot on Chrome:
[image]

Screenshot from OpenLayers:
[image]

Now due to compression the difference may not be significant (please open each image on new Tab) but its clearly visible on my end.

Interestingly the canvas is rendered as `9045` x `4523`px and not like what I've prescribed. I'm not able to understand what's happening here, tried a lot of way but it didn't worked. Any idea on how to should I approach it?

Comment: Specify `pixelRatio: 1,` in the map options if you want the map canvas size to match the css pixel size, otherwise it will use device pixels.

Comment: where should I add that property? checked the docs but didn't got the clear idea.

Comment: It is an option for the map constructor `new Map({`

Comment: Thanks, the canvas is now fixed and blurriness has slightly reduced but not completely, it still feels 5-10% blurred as compared to original. Any suggestion on how should I optimise it or would I have to live with it?

Comment: Specifying `interpolate: false,` (assuming you are using Openlayers 7) in the `new Static({` options might also help.

Comment: Apparently I was zooming way too much at Egypt, that's why it tearing up. I'll crop my GeoTIFF in Qgis and then use it as overlay to coverup that issue. By the way, what's your twitter username? I'd like to credit you on my project once its finished. (if you're comfortable).